# Hyper V Machine wont start Windows 10

Tags: virtual-machine, permissions, hyper-v

I am copying a virtual machine out of hyper v manager with the services stopped. I kept note of the ssid that I need to grant permission of. I found this excellent tutorial at

http://www.askme4tech.com/moving-virtual-machine-one-hyper-v-host-another

And it does help but I cannot find the command below to execute it on Windows 10 can someone give me some advice as to how to achieve this.

> Copy the vm hard disk, xml file and SID folder in the new Location of
>   Virtual Machines and Virtual Hard disks in the destination HYPER-V
>   Host. In the destination Server open the Cmd with Run as
>   Administrator. Type the following commands to give the appropriate
>   permissions. If you don't give the permissions the VM will fail to
>    start:

```
 icacls <path of xml fie> /grant "NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\<Virtual Machine SID> ":F
```

> For example:
>
> ```
>  icacls "C:\Program Data\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines" /grant "NT VIRTUAL 
>  MACHINE\48C5CA29-71A8-4096-9222-C1121C7D7677":F
> ```

However I cannot seem to make this command work in Windows 10 so I cannot. I was wondering what is the equivalent command for windows ten hyper v to grant the correct permissions to the user.

Comment: Does the command give an error message which you could edit into the question?

Comment: No it says as if it exceutes but the vm does not still boot which is quite strange

Comment: Why not just export and import?  Alternately, you really only need the VHD or VHDX, you could create a new VM on the new system and add the existing VHD.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue many a times and only employed temporary fixes (even `icalcs` didn't solve this) until I found a solution:

> - Open command prompt as administrator
> - Type `net localgroup administrators SERVICE /delete`
>
> followed by a reboot and starting / re-creating the VMs.

You probably don't have the SERVICE user in the admin group or its somehow missing and this may solve the permissions issue.

Acknowledgements

[Hyper-V VMs won't start (Nick Holness)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/881602-hyper-v-vms-won-t-start)